# my Php.ini File is not updating?

Tags: php

I am using `Xamp` version 5.6.3 and `PHP` vesion 5.16 . I  want to make connection between `PHP`and SQLServer.

I know the procedure to connect with `PHP`and SQL.

The problem is that when I placed the driver name of `PDO_Sqlsrv__56_ts.dll` in `Php.ini` file it would nor br effected by the Php.ini changing is not Effected .

Please tell how to solved it.

Comment: After changing php.ini file to reflect the changes we need to restart web server

Comment: First stop the server then change in `php.ini` save it. And Start your Server

Comment: Multiple time i ll restart apachi servicess but update is not efffected I add  Some Sqlsrv Driver in php file extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll these file also placed in php/Extension filder but php.ini file could not read these files I have done it at my PC nd I want to install these functuality to my frnd PC but Php.ini file is not Working Acodring to Demand ?

Answer (score 0):

Run your php.ini file 'Run As Administrator' then edit and save.
Then restart your server.
Hopefully help for you.

Comment: Multiple time i ll restart apachi servicess but update is not efffected I add Some Sqlsrv Driver in php file extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll these file also placed in php/Extension filder but php.ini file could not read these files I have done it at my PC nd I want to install these functuality to my frnd PC but Php.ini file is not Working Acodring to Demand ?

Comment: Please select your file by right mouse button and open a file to click **Run as Administrator** . I also have facing this problem.